# Routing issue in laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have following url in laravel:

1.Need to change From:

```
localhost/laravel/page/about-us/
```

to

```
localhost/laravel/about-us/
```

My Route.php is

```
Route::get('page/{title}/',
          array(
        'as'   => 'page', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@page'));
```

But When I change to this,

```
Route::get('/{title}/',
          array(
        'as'   => 'page', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@page'));
```

I have noticed that it has conflict issues with other route 
and my url is localhost/laravel/contact-us for pages    But when go to localhost/laravel/blog it give me error ----Trying to get property of non-object (View: F:\wamp\www\laravel\local\resources\views\page.blade.php) 
For blogs my route is

Route::get('blog', array( 'as' => 'blog', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@blog'));

,Plz help me

Thanx in advance

Comment: try to move that lines to the end of route.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route::get('/{title}/')` will always match any URL example `localhost/laravel/about-us/` or `localhost/laravel/blog/`

The only solution I know is to move the route below other routes, Like so:

```
 Route::get('blog', array( 'as' => 'blog', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@blog'));

 Route::get('/{title}/',
      array(
    'as'   => 'page', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@page'));
```